# Is the QtOpenGLExtensions module official?

Tags: qt, opengl, opengl-extensions

I need to do something very simple - use OpenGL extensions in my Qt code. For this, I've found [this link](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) which says the best way is the `QtOpenGLExtensions` module. But this module doesn't exist in the documentation. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

It is official. It is distributed in Qt official packages on www.qt.io.

The source code can be found in Qt git repository within the qtbase module (http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/openglextensions).

But this module is indeed not documented. My guess would be that it is because this module might have been introduced as an helper for Qt developers.

The fastest way to get a definitive answer would be to ask them on the Qt interest mailing list (http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/interest).

Comment: Thanks, I posted to that mailing list. I know it's distributed in the official packages, but since it's not documented, I'm worried that it might not be intended for general developer use, which would mean it may receive breaking changes, it may disappear, it may be unfinished, it may have gotchas... that's what I mean when I ask whether it's "official"